# How is subadditivity different from Boole's inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am studying probability theory on my own and am reading [Durrett](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf) and [Knill](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math144_1994/probability.pdf) side by side as my main references. Durrett formulates subadditivity (as a property of measures immediately proceeding from their definition) like this :$$A\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\implies\mu(A)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k)$$
where $\mu$ is a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and $A,\ A_k\in\Omega$. Knill, on the other hand does not mention subadditivity explicitly. He does, however, list $P(\bigcup_n A_n)\leq\sum_n P(A_n)$ as one of the "basic properties of the probability measure which immediately follow from the definition." Honestly though, they look quite the same to me although Wikipedia tells me the bit from Knill isn't subadditivity but Boole's inequality. Meanwhile I remain clueless.
Could somebody please explain how the two statements are different and how (if ever) they are related.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Durrett's property holds. Since $\cup_k A_k \subset \cup_k A_k$, we have $P(\cup_k A_k) \leq \sum_k P(A_k),$ which is Knill's property.

Conversely, suppose Knill's property holds and suppose $A \subset \cup_k A_k$. By monotonicity, $P(A) \leq P(\cup_k A_k)$. Hence, $P(A) \leq \sum_k P(A_k)$, which is Durrett's property.

So the two properties are equivalent for any monotonic set function. If $P$ is assumed to be a probability measure, then it is monotonic, and the two properties are equivalent.

Comment: Does monotonicity apply also to union/intersection of sets?

Comment: Monotonicity means that if $A \subset B$, then $P(A) \leq P(B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are any measurable sets. Measures are always monotonic.

Comment: Is $A\subset\bigcup_k A_k\implies P(A)\leq\sum_k P(A_k)$ a direct consequence of monotonicity?

Comment: Well, it's an immediate consequence of Boole's inequality and monotonicity, as noted in my answer. You can find a proof of Boole's inequality for probability measures on Wikipedia. It uses monotonicity, but also countable additivity, so it requires a bit more work.

Comment: To see that Durrett's property doesn't follow from monotonicity, let $P$ be defined on $\{ \emptyset, A, A^c, \Omega \}$ by $P(\emptyset)=0$, $P(A)=P(A^c)=1$, $P(\Omega)=3$. $P$ is monotonic (though not a measure) but $P(A \cup A^c) = P(\Omega) = 3 > 2 = P(A) + P(A^c)$.